# Ubuntu 12.04 android and PATH variables

Tags: android, ubuntu

im really new in linux and I have problem with set PATH variable to android. I download package from android site and unpacked it to workspace in my home directory. Then I run shell and go to my home directory and run command:

```
gedit .profile
```

Then I add to end of file lines:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=$PATH:~/workspace/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

I save it, close terminal and start it again. When I run command:

```
./android
```

I get:

```
bash: ./android: There is no such file or directory
```

Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: Write those settings to .bashrc instead of .profile. It works for me. Also try without `./` only `android`. If that works do not modify .bashrc

Comment: Trick with .bashrc helps. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax to launch the program.

```
./something
```

Refers explicitly to specifically to something in the current directory ("." means the current directory), so no path searching will be done.  This form is typically used for programs which are infrequently needed, or just-compiled programs still in their compilation directory rather than a binary directory somewhere on the search path.

To run a command which is in a directory that is in your search path, you just use the command by itself, ie

```
android
```

Or more likely

```
android &
```

so that it will release the terminal you start it from

Note that if you change your bash profile, it will not tend to take effect for the current session - easiest thing to do is to close that terminal window and open a new one, which will have a new instance of bash which has read the updated configuration.

(As an aside, your eclipse workspace directory, if that is what that is, is probably not where you want to install the android tools - most would put them somewhere such as ~/android or even system wide, such as /opt/android)